# specifying height attribute for a td in table

Tags: css, drupal-7, pdf-generation, mpdf

I want to give height for a td in table structure. I am using this in creating pdf by mpdf generator in drupal.
 I tried giving inline css to td but not reflecting at all. so please help  me regarding this.
 My requirement is like i want fixed td, it should not change depend upon the data length inside of that.

Comment: Show us some code... What did you try already?

Comment: Add styles using td in your CSS file `td{height: 20px;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default table-layout is set to `auto`. You need to set the table-layout to `fixed` to get it working for fixed td width/height:

```
table{
   table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put a div inside that td, and assign the required css to that div instead.

Example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style='display: inline-block; height: 100px;'>

      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

or:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span style='display: inline-block; height: 100px;'>

      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`td` don't seem to force fixed height. An work around can be enclosing the `td` content in a `div` and apply styles to the div.

**Below is an example:**

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.table1 td div {
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.table2 td {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>Another text hereAnother text hereAnother text hereAnother text hereAnother text hereAnother text hereAnother text here</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>

<table class="table2">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here
    </td>
    <td>Another text hereAnother text hereAnother text hereAnother text hereAnother text hereAnother text hereAnother text here
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```